# HTML FORM In Laravel Is Not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.6 and I want to use HTML Form. When I checked the Laravel Collective, just I find the HTML Form for versions of 5.4 and I install a version of 5.4 for Laravel 5.6 it installs but when I run the codes it gives an error.

```
<?php

{!! Form::open() !!}

//{!! Form::close() !!}

?>
```

Error Is This

> C:\wamp64\www\todoapp\resources\views\newpage.php

```
<?php

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

?>

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!'"`
```

Comment: {!! !!} is a syntax for opening php tags in the first place so if you use that within php tags itself, then it just gets read incorrectly.  Also, there is a Laravel blade operator for php tags `@php` and `@endphp`

Comment: also rename you file:newpage.php to newpage.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<?php` from start and `?>` from last, just keep:

```
{!! Form::open() !!} 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Thanks For your help, but one thing more see this one.{!! Form::open() !!}
echo Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address');
echo Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true);
echo Form::radio('name', 'value', true);
{!! Form::close() !!} and the result in browser is :  Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address'); Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true); Form::radio('name', 'value', true);

Comment: @SalimMaulaie whats the error here?? you don't need to use echo here in your blade template

Comment: The problem is solved, the question is answered. Accept it as working and eventually upvote it, and ask a new question if you want your application to be built step by step.

Comment: Ok, noted without of echo I save the code but the output is the same as code.     this is the output of the code see, please.                                              Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address'); Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true); Form::radio('name', 'value', true);   in the browser even I checked again and again.

Comment: as @Amarnasan suggested, better you make a new question with your updated blade code

Comment: @SalimMaulaie you should accept this answer and upvote it as it may help others later (of course if it helps you :) )

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename `newpage.php` to `newpage.blade.php` to make Laravel parse the template.

Also, as Sohel0415 said, if you have `<?php` and not closing it before the form you've shown, get rid of both `<?php` and `?>`.